# c++ lib to work with REST api for beginners

Tags: c++, json, rest

I am going to do some things using dropbox rest api in C++ and I'm looking for an easy-to use library.

Does anyone know what functionality will I need? (I only have vague idea what REST api is)

I believe I need HTTP protocol functionality and XML parsing functionality, and JSON right?
What else?

Which easy-to-use and easy-to-learn lib would you recommend me?

I found [POCO C++](http://pocoproject.org/) and it seems quite easy but I didn't find any JSON functionality...

Comment: JSON is a JavaScript Object Notation if I am not mistaken. Therefore you should not need it with C++ if you passing XML to a REST service.

Comment: Usually you use either JSON or XML for Rest. You dont need both.

Comment: @smerlin if I understand well - in some functions(=requests) the response is passed as JSON and in some as XML. But is there in the dropbox rest api any function that only returns JSON response so that I need JSON parsing functionality in my lib?

Comment: @Peter Dubec: Ah i didnt read your complete question, i thought you want to create your own REST API. Well maybe this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser

Comment: Well maybe this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser (you should be able to use any json library in addition to poco for http)

Answer (score 12):

The [C++ REST SDK](http://casablanca.codeplex.com) might have what you are looking for. It has a JSON parser and HTTP Client APIs that are very easy to use. You can check out the project on codeplex.

**Edit - 05/2016**

The Microsoft C++ REST SDK project has moved to Github at [Microsoft/cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) which says:

> The C++ REST SDK is a Microsoft project for cloud-based client-server
>   communication in native code using a modern asynchronous C++ API
>   design. This project aims to help C++ developers connect to and
>   interact with services.

The README.md has the following synopsis of what is in the SDK.

> Features - HTTP client/server, JSON, URI, asynchronous streams,
>   WebSockets client, oAuth
>
> PPL Tasks - A powerful model for composing asynchronous operations
>   based on C++ 11 features
>
> Platforms - Windows desktop, Windows Store, Windows Phone, Ubuntu, OS
>   X, iOS, and Android
>
> Support for Visual Studio 2012, 2013, and 2015 with debugger
>   visualizers
>
> NuGet package with binaries for Windows and Android platforms

Comment: Beware Linux fans: Microsoft have sewn in a pre-GCC 4.8 bug. Lazy Ubuntu, for example, still has GCC 4.7.

Comment: What do you mean with "Microsoft have sewn in a pre-GCC 4.8 bug"?

Comment: @VansFannel I think he means that if you use pre-GCC-4.8, you won't be able to compile the project.

Comment: Is there any licensing required for this?

Comment: There are two articles in Dr. Dobbs from 2013 providing an overview of the C++ REST SDK.  [Using the Microsoft C++ REST SDK](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/using-the-microsoft-c-rest-sdk/240164544) and [JSON and the Microsoft C++ REST SDK](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/json-and-the-microsoft-c-rest-sdk/240164821).

Answer (score 4):

Did you have a look at [ffead-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/), it provides wonderful support for REST and SOAP services.